# Traveling to Israel without a return ticket

Tags: us-citizens, tourist-visas, israel, one-way

Would an American citizen travelling from Japan to Israel on a tourist visa have an issue (legal or with airport security) if they don't have a return ticket?

Comment: I would edit out your second question as that's off-topic for this site

Comment: @blackbird Just to understand, in the second sentence I'm wondering whether future plans might affect the security process or legality of traveling there without a return ticket. Isn't that an important part of the question? (Or why is that off-topic?)

Comment: Of course they will, the first question they'll ask you is likely to be a variation of "What brings you here ?". Questions about moving long term are [off-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, we deal more with tourist type travels. Our sister site [expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) are more knowledgeable about these things

Comment: @Malper It would.  You don't have to have a return ticket but you have to answer a question of "How long are you planning to stay?" to the border control's satisfaction.  Or just claim Aliyah at the border.

Comment: Editing the question from "if they are applying" to "if they can say they are applying" makes no difference at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Since it is my edit, obviously I don't agree: the traveler can make these claims without intending to follow through on them. These will not help the OP get on a flight, but they might have some value at the border; e.g., eligibility for an A-1 visa.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus So is your edit suggesting that somebody lie? If not, we're in the situation where the person will to say they're going to do X if, and only if, they're actually going to do X so the change makes zero difference.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think it is up to the OP to decide if the border guard feels, for example, that finances are an issue whether to abandon the trip or to sidestep to the immigration desk and pursue a Temporary Resident visa, which depending on family history, including of course religious background, _might_ be granted on the spot without the usual pre-arrival application.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the second sentence so that this post is now on-topic. If answerers would like to add a parenthetical about how declared length and purpose of stay might affect this issue, it would certainly add to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return ticket issue is more likely to be a problem at airline check-in. British Airways (but not a large number of other airlines I have used) hold strictly to the rule that you should have a return or onward ticket when you check in. They made me buy a (refundable) return. I doubt if the BA check-in clerk will be interested in judging if you are eligible for *aliyah*.

I suppose in the unlikely event that you are asked for a return ticket only on arrival (a question I have never been asked), you could short-circuit any problem by declaring an intention to immigrate.

Comment: I would not recommend declaring an intention to immigrate; that's going to raise more flags that it lowers

Comment: 'declaring an intention to immigrate' is a very bad advise in ANY given country without a specific immigration visa or eligibility. And also - I have been asked for a return tickets ( or means ) on multiple occasions in multiple countries .

Comment: In my case, and I think in Joel's, we can pull down our pants to show eligibility to immigrate to Israel.